# what is the best way to generate a pdf, word, etc. file with react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, pdf

I know 2 libraries that do this:
1- [react-native-html-to-pdf](https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf)
2- [react-native-pdf-lib](https://github.com/Hopding/react-native-pdf-lib)
but both of them have a very large size and increase the size of apk file about 10M, on the other hand, they don't have good maintenance.
for example for the [react-native-html-to-pdf](https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf) library I constantly get `naming collision error` [mentioned in this issue](https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf/issues/107).
It seems like this extra weight doesn't worth adding such functionality, do I have any alternative or workaround for this?

Comment: I believe you should handle that in the server instead of react

Comment: @KunalMukherjee thanks for your suggestion, do you know any website that gets data in JSON or other formats and makes pdf out of it? or probably I should make it myself?

Comment: I think you should send you data as JSON to a server via react which would then process it and send a PDF back.